# Elasticsearch tokenizer to convert to lowercase without splitting when there are non-alphabets

Tags: elasticsearch

When using Elastic search's `lowercase` tokenizer, it converts text to lowercase and also breaks text into terms whenever it encounters a character which is not a letter.

Breaking of text to terms on encounter of non-alphabet is something which I'm not looking for.

I looked into `standard` and `letter` tokenizers - tried looking for a way to build a custom tokenizer but in vain.

Example: When `Postgres9` is given as input with `lowercase` tokenizer it get's converted to `['postgres','9']` but what I need is `['postgres9']` (converting to lowercase without splitting for non-alphabets)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at token filters.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenfilters.html

Something like this should do:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "standard",
  "filter":  [ "lowercase"],
  "text":      "ABC4def pqr6LMN Postgres9"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard analyzer creates tokens with special characters, so you can use a keyword analyzer and a lower case filter. Which only does converting to lowercase and nothing extra :

```
{
    "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
            "lowercaseAnalyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "filter": ["lowercase"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```